# Laravel - How to return the error message

Tags: laravel

I am trying to validate the form using this way:

```
// Start validation 
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'project_token'     =>  'required',
    'user_id'           =>  'required',
    'competitor_name'   =>  'required',
    'competitor_domain' =>  ['required','regex:/^(?!(www|http|https)\.)\w+(\.\w+)+$/'],
    'status'            =>  'required',
]);

// If validation is not sucessfull
if( $validator->fails() ) {
    return response()->json([
        'success'   =>  false,
        'message'   =>  $validator->withErrors($validator)
    ], 200);
} else {
    ....
}
```

If the validation is failed I want to get the error messages in the `message` key. How can I get the error messages ? Its showing me an error message:

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::withErrors does not exist.

Comment: Use $validator->errors()   - I suggest you have a look at the well enough documented validation section > https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: What makes you think that the validator class contains such a method?

Comment: `$validator->messages()->getMessages()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a validator error like this

```
if( $validator->fails() ) {
    return response()->json([
        'success'   =>  false,
        'message'   =>  $validator->errors()
    ], 200);
}
```

Or

```
$validator->errors()->all(); # as a Array
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, It will return proper validation message and check the validation on defined field.

```
 $request->validate([
    'project_token'     =>  'required',
    'user_id'           =>  'required',
    'competitor_name'   =>  'required',
    'competitor_domain' =>  ['required','regex:/^(?!(www|http|https)\.)\w+(\.\w+)+$/'],
    'status'            =>  'required',
], [
  'project_token.required' => 'Please Generate Project token'
]);
```

in your blade file if you add this condition after each element then if any validation error acure then it will show in front with custom message

```
 @if ($errors->has('project_token'))
      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('project_token') }}</span>
 @endif
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does your code return anything?

Comment: Where does `$errors`  come from? Also, keep in mind that the OP wants to return the raw validation errors in a JSON response. Putting them into a template does not help

Comment: well, `$errors` comes from validation which is define in controller by using their properties we can access the variable and function. I don't think so he wanted in json response. using this @shibbir get the result whichever he want's

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey @NicoHaase, Please check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75613290/wsl-acrylic-dns-proxy-which-blocked-the-port-53